# AngularJS Avoid duplicates when updating a CRUD table (normal add to table works)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, crud

I am trying to create a simple CRUD table that does not allow duplicate names.
I have been able to get the duplicate to work when adding a contact to the table, but it does not seem to be working when updating the table.

Below is my simple function that verified uniqueness of a contact:

```
// (allowed) dupCount is 0 when adding, and 1 when in update
// mode to allow saving the contact without making any changed.
var isUnqiue = function(newContact, dupCount) {
    var returnVal = true;
    var count = 0;

    for (var contact in $scope.model.contacts) {
        if (newContact.name.toUpperCase() === $scope.model.contacts[contact].name.toUpperCase()) {
          count++;
        }
    }

    if (count > dupCount) {
        returnVal = false;
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

For some reason, it the duplicate in update mode is not working at all! Even if I update 3 or 4 contacts to the same name, the 'if (count > dupCount) ... ' statement always seem to compare 1 and 1.

Here is a JSFiddle with the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/7ay9nsLv/

Simple scenario:

```
Add 'Adam, Smith'
1. Edit 'Adam, Smith', Save without Changing > Good
2. Add 'Adam, Smith' again > Duplicate Error
Add 'Adam, SmithX'
3. Edit 'Adam, SmithX' to 'Adam, Smith' > Duplicate Error
```

Also note, that the data in the table could be sorted and all, so not sure if passing $index to the controller would be too useful (unless sorting doesn't change the data index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're doing something **redudant** in your `for-loop`, you can simply use the [**Array.prototype.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to find if the index exists:

```
// Use named function to stop looping correctly
var indexExists = -1;
$scope.model.contacts.forEach(function loop(contact, index) {
  if (loop.stop) {
    return;
  }
  if (contact.name.toUpperCase() === newContact.name.toUpperCase()) {
    indexExists = index;
    loop.stop = true;
  }
});
```

or With **ES6:**

```
var indexExists = $scope.model.contacts.findIndex(function(contact) {
  return contact.name.toUpperCase() === newContact.name.toUpperCase();       
});
```

or even using [**findIndex**](http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex) method of **underscorejs**:

```
_.findIndex($scope.model.contacts, function(contact) { return contact.name.toUpperCase() === newName });
```

Then simply check:

```
return indexExists == -1 && indexExists !== idx || indexExists === idx && $scope.model.contacts[indexExists].name.toUpperCase() === newName;
```

It will returns true only if the user doesn't exists or if it exists and it's editing itself.

Now, let's go to the **error**:

You've commited 2 **mistakes**:

1. You're passing the *old* contact to your `unique` function, you should pass the *new* contact.

Change

**this:**

```
if (isUnqiue(contact, 1)) {
```

**for:**

```
if (isUnqiue($scope.model.selected, 1)) {
```

2. You're attributting the `$scope.error` to the old contact, it should be this:

```
$scope.errorContact = $scope.model.selected;
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/aspu0tt7/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the response! After updating the fiddle with your suggestions, I am getting a triplicate error instead of a duplicate error. https://jsfiddle.net/7ay9nsLv/2/

Comment: @Dev, include the **3rd.** change in your fiddle.

Comment: adding the '>=' comparison makes it so I can no longer add a contact at all because it is always comparing '0 >= 0'. https://jsfiddle.net/7ay9nsLv/3/

Comment: Well, what do you want finally? If you put 0, it means you want to allow 0 **dups**... what's wrong?

Comment: @Dev, I think I got you, give me few minutes.

Comment: Since it is always compares '0 >= 0' when adding, the statement is true so it returns (false aka it is a duplicate). I can't add any contact at all, even if it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch duplicate error not on client, but on server))
Create Uniq constraint (or primary key if it doesn't exists) on UserName field. So when you trying put or post duplicate, db throws error. You can catch it and redirect on some error page, or add something error info to response, or just show backend error.